# Computational most efficient way to convert Cartesian to Geodetic Coordinates

Tags: algorithm, coordinate-system, coordinates

As far as I understand the literature there are several ways to convert a set of geoecentric cartesian coordinates to geodetic coordinates

- [Bowring, 1976](http://openurl.ingenta.com/content/xref?genre=article&issn=0039-6265&volume=23&issue=181&spage=323)
- [Borkowski, 1989](http://www.astro.uni.torun.pl/~kb/Papers/ASS/Geod-ASS.htm)
- [Lin & Wang, 1995](http://www.springerlink.com/content/g334jv02055783k4/)
- [Toms, 1996](http://www.osti.gov/energycitations/product.biblio.jsp?osti_id=231228)
- ...

What would be the most efficient way to convert a cartesian coordinates to geodetic coordinates - most efficient meaning fastest (and most direct) when being implemented on a computer?

Comment: Do you need to perform conversions for arbitrary geodetic heights or only at nominal ground surface (zero heights)?

Comment: Ground surface will do for now, but I'm also interested in arbitrary geodetic heights in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your accuracy requirements. One iteration of Heiskanen is efficient, but it takes 3 iterations to match the accuracy of a single iteration of Bowring's 1985 method. Even Lin and Wang's algorithm cannot match the efficiency of Bowring, if the trigonometric optimizations included below are used. Therefore, for all around performance I would recommend Bowring's 1985 algorithm.

```
   -- Based on B. R. Bowring's 1985 algorithm (single iteration)
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   function ECEF_to_Geo(ECEF  : Vector3;
                        Datum : Datum_Id_Type) return Geographic_Type is
      Spheroid : Spheroid_Type := EARTH.DATUMS.Spheroid(Datum);
      x    : Meters   renames ECEF(1);
      y    : Meters   renames ECEF(2);
      z    : Meters   renames ECEF(3);
      a    : Meters   renames Models(Spheroid).Semi_Major_Axis;
      b    : Meters   renames Models(Spheroid).Semi_Minor_Axis;
      e2   : Unitless renames Models(Spheroid).Eccentricity_Squared;
      eb2  : Unitless renames Models(Spheroid).Second_Eccen_Squared;
      a2   : Scalar := a**2;
      d    : Meters := eb2*b;
      Ome2 : Unitless := 1.0 - e2;
      p2, p, r, tu, tu2, su3, cu3, Phi, Lam, tp, cp, sp, h : Scalar;
      Lat : Radians;
      Lon : Radians;
      Alt : Meters;
      Geo : Geographic_Type;
   begin -- ECEF_to_Geo
      if ((x = 0.0) and (y = 0.0)) then
         r   := abs(z);
         Phi := Scalar'copy_sign(Half_Pi, z);
         Lam := 0.0;
         h   := r - b;
      elsif (z = 0.0) then
         Phi := 0.0;
         Lam := arctan(y, x);
         p   := sqrt(x**2 + y**2);
         h   := p - a;
      else
         p2  := x**2 + y**2;
         p   := sqrt(p2);
         r   := sqrt(p2 + z**2);
         tu  := b*z*(1.0 + d/r)/(a*p);
         tu2 := tu**2;
         cu3 := (1.0/sqrt(1.0 + tu2))**3;
         su3 := cu3*tu2*tu;
         tp  := (z + d*su3)/(p - e2*a*cu3);
         Phi := arctan(tp);
         Lam := arctan(y, x);
         cp  := 1.0/sqrt(1.0 + tp**2);
         sp  := cp*tp;
         h   := p*cp + z*sp - a*sqrt(1.0 - e2*sp**2);
      end if;
      Lat := Radians(Phi);
      Lon := Radians(Lam);
      Alt := h;
      Geo := Make_Geo(Lat, Lon, Alt, Datum);
      return Geo;
   end ECEF_to_Geo;
```

Answer (score 0):

I compared about 40 ECEF-to-geodetic algorithms for a conference paper in 2020, and I concluded that the algorithm with the best combination of speed and accuracy was [Olson (1996)](https://github.com/planet36/ecef-geodetic/blob/main/olson_1996/olson_1996.c).  Furthermore, the code is in the public domain.

Of the algorithms you listed, I recommend doing 2 iterations of Bowring (1976).